# Sexism and women's clothing

Tags: women, clothing, men-women

In the West the views of burqa and hijab are very serious and Islam is viewed as oppressive and sexist because women aren't even allowed to show their hair and have to wear long clothing etc.     Is Islam sexist in terms of what women can wear since men can wear lots of different things?

The Burqa and clothing of the like is often used to convey religion/represent it and not by the will/choice of women hence why when younger kids used to wear hijab lots stop when older as it in a sense feels so restricting. I know this from experience with numerous other people and this is also probably why numerous Muslim women are trying to argue why Hijab may not be necessary.

There are a few points I want you to take into consideration when answering:

1.Are women forced to wear clothing as such

2. Why women's clothing is restricted so much and men's isn't?
3. Why can't women show their hair if it is supposed to protect their beauty isn't the face usually more beautiful so why don't you need to cover that's up.
4. What type of clothing women can wear aside from Burqa (be specific if possible and give a wide range)
5. Respond to second paragraph
6. This is a bit broad so I don't think you should do this if you want to but explain why you think it isn't sexist.

Any feedback on my question will be appreciated and this is not meant to be offensive I just seriously want to know as I haven't really found answers.

Please don't take out information either as I feel it is needed here.

Comment: Still looking for an answer the one below is not what I need, thanks.

Comment: Burqa is a cultural issue and not necessary related to Islam. And this site is not intended for discussions and helping people to answer anti-islamic websites. As to 1. Point you should explain what you mean by "forced", question 2. doesn't make sense before answering question 4 which is a list question (off-topic). What is the 2nd paragraph you are referring to. Be aware that this is too broad and many of these questions could (closure reason) have been addressed on the site before.

Comment: By forced i mean what the word forced means. Fathers are allowed to force hijab etc on their children this is probably why lots of Muslims in Weatern countries stop wearing hijab as they get older and why there aren't so many women who argue now that hijab may not even obligatory. Also regarding question 4 and 2 just switch em around and answer. I'm not anti-Islam

Comment: Also regarding the second paragraph all I was saying was that hijab/burqa is a way to represent their religion but it doesn't allow allow the women to do what they want freely. Not to mention they can't wear makeup etc but that's another thing to be talked about.

Answer (score 1):

Covering private parts with loose clothing in public is compulsory on every Muslim Man and women!

Many Muslim men are ignoring that! Men should wear loose trousers from the navel to the knee and not tight like the west, where one can see the shape of their thigh.

In regard to women, many Hadiths prove very clearly that women should wear jilbab when she prays or got out in public.

However, scholars differ on what is exactly is the jilbab - some are with the extreme view that women should cover everything apart from the eyes, but others have the that the face, hands and feet do not need to be covered!

But all scholars agree about what Allah says clearly in the Quran that women should not display their beauty (Quran 24:31).

What is most important to note, is that Hijaab is not a major thing. If a woman doesn’t wear hijaab, she is still a Muslim.

What is major, is Hayaa’. So if a women or a man haa no Hayaa’, this is major sin. Hayaa’ is a combined word, meaning feeling shame, shy and modest.

If one doesn’t feel and practice Hayaa’, then he or she could be lead on a path out of Islam all together, may Allah protect and guide us.

Abu Mas’ud reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, among the words people obtained from all prophets are this: (If you feel no shame, do as you wish.): Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 3296

So whatever A Muslim woman wants to practice, even if a woman decides not to wear loose clothes, Jilbab, or not cover her hair, it is important that she should practice and feel shame when she is outside in public.

All humans are sinful, but there are two types of sinner: a sincere sinner, and an evil lying sinner:

The sincere sinner is the one who disobeys Allah and His Messenger but they feel continuously shame and realise they are weak, and fall into sin , but seek continuous forgiveness from Allah. These people are more likely to be forgiven by Allah or at least even if they might go to Hell fire, they will inshaAllah come out of the fire due to their sincerity in their iman (faith) as it is mentioned in many Hadith.

However, the evil lying sinner is the one who tries to justify their sin by lying, changing or making their own interpretations to the wording of Quran and Hadith. They could enter Hell-Fire forever for lying to Allah and His Messenger.

Neither my mother nor my daughter wear hijab, because they find it hard to wear, due to several reasons of their own.  But one main thing is that they don’t deny that is compulsory and they try to find excuses. They don’t go and try to be their own scholar and make their own interpretation of the religion to justify their sins.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but it doesn't necessarily answer the question and my points aren't answered.